# Web crawlers and GET vs POST requests

Tags: web-applications, search-engine, web-crawler

I have heard that web crawlers are supposed to follow only GET requests and not POST ones.

In the real world is this a valid assumption?

Comment: That really depends on the type of crawler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally they do not do POST requests. This is just the current state of affairs and is not dictated anywhere, I believe. Some search engines are [experimenting with crawling forms](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html), but these are still GET requests.

Comment: Two years later, [Google changed that.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html) In fact, I have Google posting my password forgotten and login forms right now, which makes absolutely no sense to me and seems scary.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if crawlers will parse out URLs from form tags and follow them? Some will. It's a pretty safe assumption they will always use the GET verb though.

Spam bots are a different story.

Comment: My primary question was if they would ever use the POST verb.

Comment: No one with good intentions will.  But it's just a request header, and a lot of people have bad intentions.  Design for evil.

Answer (score 1):

Polite crawlers only use GET requests.  Just like polite crawlers obey the bots.txt.

However, even google is playing fast and loose with the definition of polite, their crawler has done serious bandwidth damage to some sites including stackoverflow.

Comment: I believe they obey robots.txt.